# Datagrid/Listview rowspan in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, datagrid

I want to create a datagrid similar to the image. Please help me to do datagrid/listview rowspan or cell merging in wpf. Sample image and xaml code are as follows,

[image]

```
      <DataGrid Name="DG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding TextandNumbers}" >               

        <DataGrid.Columns> 
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="C">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Texts}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="D">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="E">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: If it was the first column we could have achieved it using row header.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem !

Comment: If it's static data means you could achieve it using grid.